# How to set dynamic container height related to it's next container'a height in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want my second (blue) container height should match the first (red) container height.

Here is the preview now,

[image]

And here is the code I've done.

```
ListView(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
  children: <Widget>[
    Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(color: Colors.red, height: 100, width: 100,),
        Container(color: Colors.blue, height: 50, width: 50,),
      ],
    ),
    Divider(),
    Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(color: Colors.red, height: 300, width: 100,),
        Container(color: Colors.blue, height: 50, width: 50,),
      ],
    ),
  ],
)
```

So, how can I make the blue container automatically match the red container height?

Comment: So, I’m confused. you have explicitly given the height in both the blue and the red containers. What are you trying to do? I made a dartpad file here to further the discussion: https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b

Comment: oops.  wrong link.  Here's the correct one: https://dartpad.dev/f917596f5c574f8d792b6ecffcfa08e2

Comment: thank you so much for your interest to help me, basically, the first container will have text, the first container height can be anything depending on its child. Sorry I don't know how to save durtpade.

Comment: @WilliamTerrill, My actual goal is to create this, don't know how to achieve stepper,

![](https://i.ibb.co/DDBjWQg/b9689691-f566-4b7a-9c8b-f113c1251ea8.jpg)

I've created this, 

![](https://i.ibb.co/vvbLHBB/Annotation-2020-03-05-024802.jpg)

Comment: so, to make sure I understand.. the "red" in your example will be the part in your second link that says, "February 24,20" and the blue will be the rest of the box? (the hindi written above, and the three buttons)?  Is that correct?

Comment: Is that correct?  I'm still not sure what you mean by 'stepper'

Comment: @WilliamTerrill thank you so much for the time you are spending the time to help me, I really appreciate this.  On the first photo you will see a gradient circle and a gray line. Together line and small circle, I'm calling this, Stepper. I want to make stepper on left side of the row. In the second photo I've made the right side part. Want to make left side stepper line. I want to make stepper on left side of the row. In the second photo I've made the right side part. Want to make left side stepper line.

Comment: To do that I need a vertical match parent function for left side widget depending on the right side part. The right side part is not a fixed size it depends on the child text, So I need a way to auto match parent height on left side widget depending on its right side widget. If I could find the way to make height match parent depending the next widget of it may be I can draw stepper line with stack or custom painter.

Comment: ok. I understand the issue. I updated my gist to reflect what you want. I highlighted the three heights of the line with a commented arrow. The code is here: https://dartpad.dev/f917596f5c574f8d792b6ecffcfa08e2 I'll take a look at it tomorrow. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your help meant me a lot. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the height parameter of the child you want to expand and use [IntrinsicHeight](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html) class like below.

```
ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
        children: <Widget>[
          IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(color: Colors.red, height: 100, width: 100,),
                Container(color: Colors.blue,width: 100,),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Divider(),
          IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(color: Colors.red, height: 300, width: 100,),
                Container(color: Colors.blue, width: 50,),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
```

[image]